# How to get Bash shell history range

Tags: linux, bash, history, grep

How  can I get/filter history entries in a specific range?

I have a large history file and frequently use

`history | grep somecommand`

Now, my memory is pretty bad and I also want to see what else I did around the time I entered the command.

For now I do this:
get match, say `4992 somecommand`, then I do

```
history | grep 49[0-9][0-9]
```

this is usually good enough, but I would much rather do it more precisely, that is see commands from 4972 to 5012, that is 20 commands before and 20 after.

I am wondering if there is an easier way? I suspect, a custom script is in order, but perhaps someone else has done something similar before.

Comment: For history manipulation there are 2 built-ins: http://gnu.huihoo.org/bash-2.02/html_node/bashref_73.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can tell `grep` to print some lines surrounding the match, e.g., 3 before and 5 after:

```
history | grep -B 3 -A 5 somecommand
```

`grep -C 4` is equivalent to `grep -A 4 -B 4`.

But often you won't know precisely how many lines you want in advance. So use less and search inside it. You can even launch the search from the command line:

```
history | less +/somecommand
```

Comment: very cool trick with `less`! Didn't know you could do that

Comment: Very nice indeed... I can see "around" the command I'm looking for, even when I'm not really looking for it specifically but I remember using it when I used another relevant command! Good stuff tnx.

Answer (score 9):

Try fc:

```
fc -l 4972 5012
```

... it is a bash builtin command. (so don't try it in tcsh :>)

Answer (score 4):

try `history | grep -C20 '^4992'`